# Count Column in multiple inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, count, inner-join

i want to get count of groupby (bebleiotheque.type), its work but whene i add multiple many2many fields to get multiple books or multiple employer for each bebeliotheque row, my count get rise

howa to get real count of groupby (bebeliotheque type)

[Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2866de8f889039d627874d9b329f7833)

take a look in my app list bebeliotheque, i regroup all same bebeliotheque name but I have an incorrect (count)

preview

image > http://rezigdev.com/image_202112522328.jpg

video > https://rezigdev.com/preview.mp4

sql query

```
SELECT 
        bibliotheque.name, GROUP_CONCAT(book.name)  as books,  GROUP_CONCAT(employers.name)  as employers, COUNT(bibliotheque.name)
FROM 
        bibliotheque
        left join 
          x_x_bibliotheque_book 
          ON x_x_bibliotheque_book.bibliotheque_id = bibliotheque.id
        left join 
          book 
          ON x_x_bibliotheque_book.book_id = book.id
          
        left join 
          x_x_bibliotheque_employers 
          ON x_x_bibliotheque_employers.bibliotheque_id = bibliotheque.id
        left join 
          employers 
          ON x_x_bibliotheque_employers.employer_id = employers.id
          
          
Group BY 
        bibliotheque.name
```

Comment: again , in plain english try to explain what's your logic, what are you trying to count? explain it

Comment: I'n not sure wether I understand what you want, but I try: If you replace the COUNT(...) in you statement by `COUNT(distinct book.name)` would this bring the expected result? Because you want to count the number of books in each bib?

Comment: Please put everything needed to ask your question in your post, not just at a link. Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please use standard spelling & punctuation. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. For code questions give a [mre].

Comment: Duplicate of [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12464037/3404097)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution :
COUNT(distinct bibliotheque.id)